# f2py: error f90 not supported by GnuFCompiler needed for source_file.f90

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to install a Python package that relies on extensions built from Fortran 90 using f2py, but I get the following error:

```
error: f90 not supported by GnuFCompiler needed for source_file.f90
```

I have both gfortran and g77 installed, what is going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

By default, f2py prefers the GNU Fortran 77 compiler `--fcompiler=gnu` over the GNU Fortran 95 compiler `--fcompiler=gnu95`.  If you have both `g77` and `gfortran` on your path, then f2py will, use `g77`, which cannot build Fortran 90 extensions.

If you would prefer for numpy to use `gfortran` over `g77`, you can either pass the `--fcompiler=gnu95` flag to setup.py when building your code, or you can modify your numpy installation's `numpy/distutils/fcompiler/__init__.py` file [*] from:

```
_default_compilers = (
# sys.platform mappings
('win32', ('gnu','intelv','absoft','compaqv','intelev','gnu95','g95',
           'intelvem', 'intelem')),
('cygwin.*', ('gnu','intelv','absoft','compaqv','intelev','gnu95','g95')),
('linux.*', ('gnu','intel','lahey','pg','absoft','nag','vast','compaq',
            'intele','intelem','gnu95','g95','pathf95')),
('darwin.*', ('nag', 'absoft', 'ibm', 'intel', 'gnu', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'pg')),
('sunos.*', ('sun','gnu','gnu95','g95')),
('irix.*', ('mips','gnu','gnu95',)),
('aix.*', ('ibm','gnu','gnu95',)),
# os.name mappings
('posix', ('gnu','gnu95',)),
('nt', ('gnu','gnu95',)),
('mac', ('gnu','gnu95','pg')),
)
```

to

```
_default_compilers = (
# sys.platform mappings
('win32', ('gnu95','intelv','absoft','compaqv','intelev','gnu','g95',
           'intelvem', 'intelem')),
('cygwin.*', ('gnu95','intelv','absoft','compaqv','intelev','gnu','g95')),
('linux.*', ('gnu95','intel','lahey','pg','absoft','nag','vast','compaq',
            'intele','intelem','gnu','g95','pathf95')),
('darwin.*', ('nag', 'absoft', 'ibm', 'intel', 'gnu95', 'gnu', 'g95', 'pg')),
('sunos.*', ('sun','gnu95','gnu','g95')),
('irix.*', ('mips','gnu95','gnu',)),
('aix.*', ('ibm','gnu95','gnu',)),
# os.name mappings
('posix', ('gnu95','gnu',)),
('nt', ('gnu95','gnu',)),
('mac', ('gnu95','gnu','pg')),
)
```

This will prioritize gfortran over g77, allowing you to build Fortran 90 extensions for your Python code using f2py.

[*] *If you've never modified an installed Python module before, you will probably we wondering where to find it.  From your Python prompt:*

```
import numpy; print numpy.__file__
```